# Relationship between power spectral density of window function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let's say you have a continuous signal $\sigma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. You want to do the Fourier transform at time $t$, so you window it with some function $\omega : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, and you look at their product defined by $p(t) = \sigma(t)\omega(t)$.

Let's assume the windowing function is symmetric around 0 and real. Denote the Fourier transforms of the functions with hats: $\hat{\sigma}$, etc...

We are interested in the power spectral density (PSD) of $\sigma$ (at a certain frequency $f$)

It can be defined as
$$
PSD(\sigma, f) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \lvert \hat \sigma(f)\rvert^2
$$
But to avoid doing the computation for the whole range of $\sigma$, we instead do it for $\sigma \cdot \omega$.

What is the relationship between $PSD(\sigma, f)$ and $PSD(\sigma \cdot \omega, f$)?

From the literature it looks like they are just scalar multiples of each other, scaled by a factor independent of $f$, but I cannot find any sources. (nor prove it directly...)

Does anyone have any sources/proofs on the relationships between these two? (the discrete case is fine)

Thanks!

Comment: The PSD of the signal is convoluted (in the frequency domain) with the PSD of the window. There’s no simple formula that doesn’t involve looking at a range of frequencies.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thank you for the comment. Maybe my question stems from a confusion about windowing. Maybe the real question is that I can't find any explanation by the choice of scaling factor people choose when applying windowing. (ie multiply the PSD with something)